# Typo 3: Create user on FE login

Tags: php, authentication, typo3, frontend, createuser

**The situation:** 
I build an authentication service that uses Basic Authentication to check if the user exists on an external database and fetches some data. The users in question only exist on the external database.

**The problem:** 
Typo3 needs to have an user entry in the fe_user table to login the user.
So whenever this entry does not exist, the user cannot login.

**What I want to do:** 
Create the user in the authentication service to avoid using a sql dump from the external database and ensure that synchronisation is possible.

**The relevant code:**

```
public function authUser(array $user) {
    $a_user = $this->login['uname'];
    $a_pwd = $this->login['uident_text'];
    $url = 'https://soliday.fluchtpunkt.at/api/queryMediaItems';
    $data = json_decode('{"language":"de-at"}');
    $basicAuth = base64_encode("$a_user:$a_pwd");

    // use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
    $options = array (
            'http' => array (
                    'header' => array(
                                "Content-Type: application/json",
                                "Accept: application/json",
                                "Authorization: Basic {$basicAuth}"
                            ),
                    'method' => 'POST',
                    'content' => '{"language":"de-at"}'
            ) 
    );
    $context = stream_context_create ( $options );
    $result = file_get_contents ($url, false, $context);
    $response = gzdecode($result);
    $checkUser = $this->fetchUserRecord ( $this->login ['uname'] );
    if (!is_array($checkUser)&& $result!== FALSE) {
        $this->createUser();
    }
    // failure
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        return static::STATUS_AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE_BREAK;
    }
    $this->processData($response);

    // success
    return static::STATUS_AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS_BREAK;
}

public function createUser() {
    $username = $this->login ['uname'];
    $password = $this->login ['uident_text'];
    $record = $GLOBALS ['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTgetSingleRow ( '*', 'fe_users', "username = '" . $username . "' AND disable = 0 AND deleted = 0" );
    if (! $record) {
        // user has no DB record (yet), create one using defaults registered in extension config
        // password is not important, username is set to the user's input
        $record = array (
                'username' => $username,
                'password' => $password,
                'name' => '',
                'email' => '',
                'disable' => '0',
                'deleted' => '0',
                'pid' => $this->config ['storagePid'],
                'usergroup' => $this->config ['addUsersToGroups'],
                'tstamp' => time () 
        );
        if (t3lib_extMgm::isLoaded ( 'extbase' )) {
            $record ['tx_extbase_type'] = $this->config ['recordType'];
        }
        $GLOBALS ['TYPO3_DB']->exec_INSERTquery ( 'fe_users', $record );
        $uid = $GLOBALS ['TYPO3_DB']->sql_insert_id ();
        $record = $GLOBALS ['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTgetSingleRow ( '*', 'fe_users', 'uid = ' . intval ( $uid ) );
    }
    $_SESSION [$this->sessionKey] ['user'] ['fe'] = $record;
}
```

the ext_localconf.php file:

```
   <?php
if (!defined('TYPO3_MODE')) {
    die ('Access denied.');
}

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addService(
    $_EXTKEY,
    'auth' /* sv type */,
    'AuthService' /* sv key */,
    array(
        'title' => 'GET Authentication service',
        'description' => 'Authenticates users with GET request.',

        'subtype' => 'getUserFE, authUserFE',

        'available' => true,
        'priority' => 90,
        'quality' => 90,

        'os' => '',
        'exec' => '',

        'className' => Plaspack\professionalZoneLogin\Service\AuthService::class,
    )
);
```

Comment: you might inspect other authentification extenions like [ig_ldap_sso_auth](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/ig_ldap_sso_auth/), which create fe_users while login.

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ I believe I have looked at that before, but I could not find where they are creating the users, can you pinpoint me?

Comment: We use version 3.2.2 of ig_ldap_sso_auth, where I can find in Classes/Library/Authentification.php a method `synchroniseUser()` which calls `Typo3UserRepository::add()`

Comment: tried all that did not work. When I try to login it loads for a while and then tells me the default login error message. No errors in the logs or anything like that. No entry in the db either

Answer (score 0):

You should extend AuthenticationService with your own code, way of doing that is described here https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Xclasses/Index.html

Comment: that's what I did with
class AuthService extends \TYPO3\CMS\Sv\AuthenticationService

Comment: can you please copy here code from ext_localconf.php which you added to extend this class?

Comment: Sorry probably was not clear enough, the AuthService itself is working. It's the creating a user bit that isn't. Everything else is working fine. Added the ext_localconf in the main post tho.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's related, but `t3lib_extMgm` should be `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility` unless you're using TYPO3 6.

You can also see if you get any SQL errors by calling `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_error()`.

Comment: Thanks for that, does not look like I am getting any SQL errors. Almost feels like it's not even getting to that part of the code.